# How to create a responsive zig-zag border using only css. The starting and ending pattern must match

Tags: html, css

I want to create a zig-zag border in css which is responsive, i.e. the zig-zag border must adjust itself to fit perfectly according to width of the container.

I was able to create this:
[image: Image1]

But on changing the width it's output is :
[image: Image2]

I want to perfectly fit the zig-zag pattern like above image on changing the width of the container.

It would be helpful if I could also add some radius at peak points like this :
[image: Image3]

Here is the code so far

```css
.container {
  width: 664px;
}

.sub-container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 40px;
  height: 200px;
}

.upper-zigzag {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffffff 25%, transparent 25%) 0px 0,
    linear-gradient(225deg, #ffffff 25%, transparent 25%) 0px 0;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 32px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.lower-zigzag {
  position: relative;
  background:
    linear-gradient(315deg, #ffffff 25%, transparent 25%) -28px -30px,
    linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 25%, transparent 25%) -28px -30px;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  margin-top: -30px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sub-container"></div>
    <div class="upper-zigzag"></div>
    <div class="lower-zigzag"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: No pictures displaying?

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: @AHaworth added the code. Thanks!

Comment: To make the triangles always be displayed fully on any page width you'll have to grow and shrink them I think?

Comment: You'll need to use relative units (eg %) rather than px.

Comment: @AHaworth I did it with percentages but I was able to make it responsive to a little extent but not fully responsive. I would appreciate it if you could try something.